# Listen to eloquent model event in an observer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't find the syntax to listen to eloquent events in my event handler.

I subscribed my observer like so

```
Event::subscribe('Animekyun\Handlers\Events\EloquentEventHandler');
```

This observer is self-handling and is implemented like so:

```
namespace Animekyun\Handlers\Events;

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class EloquentEventHandler
{

    public function onEpisodeSave($event) {
        dd('test');
    }

    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->listen('eloquent.saved: episode', 'Animekyun\Handlers\Events\EloquentEventHandler@onEpisodeSave');
    }

}
```

I don't know how to listen to any eloquent event in this form. I'm sure there is a way to listen to an event without doing things like:

```
User::creating(function($user)
{
    if ( ! $user->isValid()) return false;
});
```

EDIT:
the user model

```
<?php

use Laracasts\Presenter\PresentableTrait;
use Conner\Likeable\LikeableTrait;

class Episode extends \Eloquent
{
    use PresentableTrait;
    use LikeableTrait;

    public static $rules = [
        'show_id'        => 'required',
        'episode_number' => 'required',
    ];

    // Add your validation rules here
    protected $presenter = 'Animekyun\Presenters\EpisodePresenter';

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'links', 'show_id', 'episode_number', 'format_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'screenshots'];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
    {
        return $search;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'created_by');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Show');
    }

    public function format()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Format');
    }

    public function rating()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Rating', 'rateable');
    }

    public function getLinksAttribute()
    {
        return (array) json_decode($this->attributes['links'], true);
    }

    public function setLinksAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['links'] = json_encode($value);
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: How is the `episode` class defined?

Comment: like any other model. It extends the `Eloquent` class and has some relationship methods. Nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the class declaration? My guess is it's not working because of namespace and probably case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening to the wrong event. Because string comparison is case sensitive, you should be listening to the `eloquent.saved: Episode` event. Note the capital `E` on `Episode`. The class name isn't converted to lowercase as the event is fired.

Additionally, while this doesn't apply to your particular case, it should be noted that if the class is defined under a namespace, like `App` for example, you need to include that namespace as well (i.e. `App\Episode`).